# Get element from selector given an index with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, indexing

```
var items = $(".myClass");
```

The code above returns a number of items when used to select all elements. How can I select a specific element, for example the second one? Neither `items(2)` nor `items[2]` works.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
items.eq(2) // gets the third element as a jQuery object (zero-based index)
```

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/eq#index

Comment: +1 Because I always use items.get(2) and I didn't know about this method. Does anyone know the difference?

Comment: @Andy: get(#) and [#] are the same and return the DOM element while eq(#) returns the jQuery object which wraps the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

arrays are zero based so you need  `items[1]` for the second one

Answer (score 0):

2nd item would be `items[ 1 ]` in your case. Also the code you've provided works perfectly for me (with `items[ 1 ]`).

Answer (score 0):

try

var items = $(".myClass"); 
    alert($(items)[1]);