# How to return array of jQuery object with selector

Tags: jquery

I am trying to retrieve an array of jquery object from selector, so I would not have to re-query them again for modification later.

But, while I testing with the code, I find that the jquery selector returns array as html element if it does not query specific element.

```
//HTML
<div id='nav'>
    <div class='menu'>menu 1</div>
    <div class='menu'>menu 2</div>
    <div class='menu'>menu 3</div>
    <div class='menu'>menu 4</div>
    <div class='menu'>menu 5</div>
</div>​


//JS

//this works
$('#nav .menu:eq(0)').html('haha');

//this does not    
$('#nav .menu').get(0).html('halo w');​ 

-> Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'html'
```

My question is why does it return html element and not jquery object.How can I retrieve an array of jquery objects from selector.

Here's the JSFiddle example.

http://jsfiddle.net/mochatony/K5fJu/7/

Comment: Also you can use `$("#nav .menu").get(0).innerHTML = "haha";`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: get certain element from selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797205/jquery-get-certain-element-from-selector)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`.get(i)` returns the DOM element. What you want is one of these:

```
$('#nav .menu').first()
$('#nav .menu').eq(0)
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/filtering/ for a list of possible filter functions.

Answer (score 4):

`$('#nav .menu')` does return an array of the matched elements. But to use it you have to access it properly.  Consider the following code

```
var x = $('#nav .menu'); //returns the matching elements in an array

//(recreate jQuery object)
$(x[1]).html('Hello'); //you can access the various elements using x[0],x[1] etc.
```

above is same as

```
$($('#nav .menu')[1]).html('Hello');​
```

If you do a `alert(x.length)` u'll get 5 as an alert which indicates the length of the array as per your example.

[JSFIDDLE Example](http://jsfiddle.net/lonewolfs/PvRem/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#nav .menu:eq(0)');
```

or

```
$('#nav .menu:first');
```

or

```
$('#nav .menu').first();
```

or

```
$('#nav .menu').eq(0);
```