# jQuery multiple element selection to array of jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Originally I had something like this:

```
var rows = 
[
    $('#view-content > .row:nth-child(1) > .row-content'),
    $('#view-content > .row:nth-child(2) > .row-content'),
    $('#view-content > .row:nth-child(3) > .row-content'),
    $('#view-content > .row:nth-child(4) > .row-content')
];
```

Which is an array of jQuery objects. I could do `rows[0]` to get the first jQuery object and `rows[0][0]` to get the first jQuery object`s "native" DOM element.

Then I tried to do this:

`var rows = $('#view-content > .row > .row-content');`

But using `rows[0][0]`no longer works and returns `undefined`.

I also tried:

`var rows = Array.from($('#view-content > .row > .row-content'));`

But `rows[0][0]` still does not work.

So what I want is a simple way to turn a multiple element jQuery selector into a **reqular array of jQuery objects**. How can I do this? [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479879/how-to-return-array-of-jquery-object-with-selector) suggests using `eq` and such, so technically I could loop through `$('#admin-view-content > .row > .row-content')` selection and `.eq` everything one-by-one into a normal array, but I wonder if there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Sure. Give me a minute.

Comment: `rows[0]` would return you native DOM element with `var rows = $('#view-content > .row > .row-content');` So what is the issue? Also note `var rows = 
[...]` and `var rows = $('#view-content >)` are not same so how they can behave same and __Why do you need array of jQuery objects__?

Comment: `$('#view-content > .row > .row-content');` output is array. all maching selector. you can access `row[0]`

Comment: @Satpal I want to make the application get all those elements regardless of how many of them there are. Rest of the code requires that row[0] is the jquery object and row[0][0] is the native object, so I want an array of jQuery objects to keep rest of the code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So what I want is a simple way to turn a multiple element jQuery
>   selector into a reqular array of jQuery objects.

You can use **jquery's** `filter` and `map`

```
var rows = $( '#view-content > .row' )
    .filter( ( i, v ) => i < 4 ) //return only elements with index less than 4(index is 0 based)
    .map( (i, v) => $(v).find(".row-content") ); //map and return their inner row content
```

**Note**

- No need for `filter`, if all the `rows`'s inner `.row-content` has to be returned.

Comment: This one works, but I had to do it the old way: `var rows = $('#view-content > .row').map(function(i, v) { return $(v).find(".row-content"); });`. Thank you!

Comment: @Piwwoli Sorry, I didn't get this part *but I had to do it the old way* .

Comment: Some of our build tools do not seem to like the more new lambda syntax `(i, v) =>`, so instead I just gave the map-function an "old fashion" anonymous function `function(i, v) { return $(v).find(".row-content"); }`.

Comment: @Piwwoli ohh, I get it. Out of curiosity (not related to this question), which build or compression tool do you use?

Comment: It's pretty basic but gets the job done. Just a bunch of gulp tasks combined with gulp-minify, gulp-less and gulp-browserify: https://pastebin.com/ca4a7W8T The gulp-minify is brobably outdated and does not understand how to minify lambda-syntax so the compiled script throws an error.

Comment: Cool, I am not able to reach this link from my network. Gulp is a common tool used these days. Thanks for the info though.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Array of single JQuery elements you can do that:

```
var rows = [];
$('#view-content > .row > .row-content').each(function () { rows.push(this); });
```

then rows looks like this:

```
[elem:JQueryElement, elem:JQueryElement, elem:JQueryElement]; // just a element array
```

Comment: This is a well working solution as well, thank you! I was looking for a "oneliner", however, so I am going with gurvinder's answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

While you've already accepted an answer, it seems your misunderstandings regarding your attempts have yet to be addressed; so I'll take a moment to try and help with that:

> …I tried to do this:

```
var rows = $('#view-content > .row > .row-content');
```

> But using `rows[0][0]` no longer works and returns `undefined`.

With your selector you retrieve a jQuery Object, rather than an Array of jQuery Objects; so in this case using `rows[0]` will return the native DOM node from the jQuery Object. Using `rows[0][0]` is attempting to retrieve value of the zeroth property of the retrieved DOM node (which, as you note, is undefined).

So, obviously, if you want the DOM node from a given index, you just have to use:

```
rows[<index>]
```

> …what I want is a simple way to turn a multiple element jQuery selector into a [regular] array of jQuery objects.

Given the code you've posted and what that code seems to be attempting to do, I honestly don't believe you really want an Array of jQuery Objects, because your code seems to be trying to retrieve regular DOM nodes from the various Arrays and Objects you've created. So, while I'll answer your explicit question later, I'll first address the implicit questions.

You provided no code, unfortunately, so I'll use the following HTML to illustrate my answers and approaches:

```
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>
<p>paragraph 7</p>
```

There are many ways to create Arrays of DOM nodes, and limiting those Arrays to the first four nodes (indices `0` through `3`). For example:

```
// using Array.from() to convert the Array-like
// static NodeList returned from document.querySelectorAll():
let arrayOfNodes = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('p')
// slices that resulting Array to retain only the elements
// from an index of 0 up to - but not including - the index
// of 4:
).slice(0, 4);

// using the returned Array as a demo of successful selection:
arrayOfNodes.forEach(
  DOMNode => DOMNode.style.color = 'limegreen'
);
```

```js
let arrayOfNodes = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('p')
).slice(0, 4);

arrayOfNodes.forEach(
  DOMNode => DOMNode.style.color = 'limegreen'
);
```

```html
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>
<p>paragraph 7</p>
```

With jQuery you can do much the same thing, and then use the jQuery Object itself, rather than an Array, to operate on those elements:

```
// here we select all <p> elements with an index of less-than 4
// (the jQuery ':lt(4)' pseudo-selector):
$('p:lt(4)')
  // and then do something with those elements:
  .css('color','limegreen');
```

```js
$('p:lt(4)').css('color','limegreen');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>
<p>paragraph 7</p>
```

However if, after initially selecting those elements you wish to use the DOM node, you can simply cache the retrieved elements in a variable, and access a specific DOM node or jQuery object like so:

```
// caching the <p> elements of index < 4:
let firstFour = $('p:lt(4)');

// using the jQuery Object, via the eq(<index>) method:
firstFour.eq(0).css('color', 'limegreen');

// using the DOM Node, via [<index>] notation:
firstFour[1].style.color = 'red';
```

```js
let firstFour = $('p:lt(4)');

firstFour.eq(0).css('color', 'limegreen');

firstFour[1].style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>
<p>paragraph 7</p>
```

From the above I hope you see why I don't think you require an Array (given that the jQuery Object itself gives you Array-like access to either the jQuery Object, for use with jQuery methods, or to the underlying DOM nodes themselves).

Now, while I still aren't convinced you actually *want* this answer, here's one way to create an Array of jQuery Objects:

```
// retrieve all the <p> elements:
let test = $('p')
  // slice the resulting, Array-like, jQuery Object
  // to retain only the first four elements:
  .slice(0, 4)
  // use map() to create an Array from the jQuery Object:
  .map(function(){
    // creating a jQuery Object from the current element,
    // and returning it to Array being formed:
    return $(this);
  });

// accessing the jQuery Object within the created Array,
// using [<index>] notation:
test[0]
  // chaining with a jQuery method to show that a jQuery
  // Object has been retrieved:
  .css('color', 'limegreen');
```

```js
let test = $('p').slice(0, 4).map(function() {
  return $(this);
});

test[0].css('color', 'limegreen');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>paragraph 1</p>
<p>paragraph 2</p>
<p>paragraph 3</p>
<p>paragraph 4</p>
<p>paragraph 5</p>
<p>paragraph 6</p>
<p>paragraph 7</p>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).
- jQuery:

  - [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
  - [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
  - [`:lt()` Selector](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/).
  - [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
  - [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/).

Comment: Great answer. I do want an array of jQuery objects because I am modifying hardcoded code that I did not make myself. Rest of the code operates with an array of jQuery objects, as it was hardcoded to fill the rows array with those row-elements. I don't want to touch the rest of the code - I just want to remove hardcoded part of four rows by selecting all the row elements and making a similar array out of them so that the rest of the code still works. The rest of the code takes the array length into account (so the length doesn't matter), but uses rows[0][0]'s and I don't want to touch that.

Comment: Well, I'm glad that I was able to help in some way; but my honest opinion is that you're accruing a code-debt by supporting a potentially obsolete/inefficient hard-coded back-end. At some point somebody's very likely going have to do a major rewrite of that, and all code that interfaces with it.